# ReactNative: Dismiss Keyboard on scroll of Multiline TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm using a multiline TextInput and I would like to dismiss the keyboard while scrolling using the onScroll() props

The Code I tried:

```
<View>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(bodyContent) => this.setState({bodyContent})}
    value = {this.state.bodyContent}
    editable = {true}
    multiline={true}
    onScroll = {() => Keyboard.dismiss() }
  />
</View>
```

Also noticed that onScroll events don't get fired on a scroll (even tried with console.log( ) )

- react-native": "0.57.3"
- Platform: IOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the onScroll is not firing. There is an issue about this topic, however because the person who created the issue used an out of date version of RN, the issue was closed. You should open a new issue with the newest release of RN. I used RN 0.59 so its definitely still an issue.

Link to issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20309

Here is my implementation that can be copied and pasted anywhere:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Keyboard } from 'react-native';

const FormInput = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={setText}
        value={text}
        editable
        multiline
        onScroll={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

export default FormInput;
```